# Copy text via button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, ctrl

I made a button:

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
var value = "text I want to copy";
btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("copy"));
btn.onclick = function(){
// this is something I want, demo code:
copy(value);
console.log("copy successful");
};
// and then when I ctrl + V (paste) to somewhere else, the output should be this:
"text I want to copy"
```

I hope you get the idea, I hope someone can help me this.

Comment: Last time I investigated it was only possible using a third-party flash plugin like https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard.

Comment: btw, the varible could be an array , a list of text, ex: a list of emails.

Comment: I also want it to be able to paste outside of the windows, I use keycode and it works only in the same document.

Comment: you can't do this without the user pressing [ctrl]+[c] themselves...